# PHP File download with original filename

Tags: php, curl, download

I'm searching for a possibility to download a file with PHP and keep its original name.

This should work for direct links to a file ("foo.bar/test.zip") and for downloads who are proxied through PHP files ("foo.bar/download.php?fileid=12345" <- this would open a save-as prompt with test.zip as given name).
Is there a possibility in PHP that I could use to do this?

I tried different possibilities (fopen, cURL, file_get_content, etc.). But all possibilities I've found required me to manually set the new filename in order to save it locally.

Even better would be if I could proxy the remote file through my script (with it's original name!) to the client who is calling the script, without saving it temporarily.
I found the following snippet which accomplishes this exact thing

```
$fp = fopen($_POST["url"], 'rb');
foreach (get_headers($_POST["url"]) as $header)
{
    header($header);
}
fpassthru($fp);
```

The file I get to download is of the right size but has the wrong name (it has the name of the called PHP script, in my case downloader.php instead of e.g. test.zip).

Any idea how to accomplish this would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

May be something like this will help:

```
$quoted = sprintf('"%s"', addcslashes(basename($file), '"\\'));
$size   = filesize($file);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $quoted); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
```

Just replace $file with the file you want to be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks, this works if I use a direct link to a file. But it won't work if I'd use a link to a php file whichs proxies the requested file to me. Do you know a possibility how I could achieve this?

Comment: what are you using in the proxying script?